# sunspot_rails Levenshtein distance operator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I'm using sunspot_rails (on rails3) to interface my rails app to a solr server. I would really like to perform fuzzy searches using the ~ operator. Anyway it seems that this is not supported. I'm now falling back to use EdgeNGrams but I'm not completely satisfied by the results.

Any suggestion? Is anyone been able to make Levenshtein distance searches through sunspot_rails?

**SOLVED**

The [adjust_solr_params](http://outoftime.github.com/sunspot/docs/classes/Sunspot/DSL/Adjustable.html) method provided by Sunspot allow you to override the default query parser so you can use one that supports ~. Basically, I made Sunspot use the lucene query parser setting the defType pameter:

> ```
> Post.search do
>    adjust_solr_params do |params|
>        params[:q] = 'field_name:foo~'
>        params[:defType] = 'lucene'
>    end
> end
> ```

Comment: did not work for me... 
do you have to escape '~' somehow?